# how can i send payload with multiple requests in python using threadpoolexecutor and requests?

Tags: python, json, multithreading, python-requests, python-multithreading

i have managed to send multiple requests to a web api at the same time through ThreadPoolExecutor and get the json responses but i cant send requests with payload 
would you be kind enough to see my code and suggest me an edit to send payload (data , header)
i just dont know how to send payload
.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor 
import requests
from timer import timer
URL = 'whatever.com'
payload = {'aaaaa': '0xxxxxxx'}
headers = {
'abc': 'xyz',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
def fetch(session, url):
 with session.post(url) as response:
    print(response.json())
@timer(1, 1)
def main():
 with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    with requests.session() as session:
        executor.map(fetch, [session] * 100, [URL] * 100)
        executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you specify a "payload" using the *data* keyword argument on the call to the `post` method. But if you want to send it in JSON format, then you should use the *json* keyword argument:

```py
session.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

(If the header specified `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`, as yours does, and if `payload` were already a `JSON` string, which yours is *not*, then you would be correct to use the *data* keyword argument for then you would not need any JSON conversion. But here you clearly need to first have `requests` convert a Python dictionary to a JSON string for transmission and that is why the *json* argument is being used. You do not really need to explicitly specify a *header* argument since `requests` will provide an appropriate one for you.)

Now I know this is a just a "dummy" program fetching the same URL 100 times. In a more realistic version you would be fetching 100 different URLs but you would, of course, be using the same `Session` instance for each call to `fetch`. You could therefore simplify the program in the following way:

```py
from functools import partial

...

def main():
 with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    with requests.Session() as session:
        worker = partial(fetch, session) # first argument will be session
        executor.map(worker, [URL] * 100)
        # remove following line
        #executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

Note that I have also commented out your explicit call to method `shutdown` since `shutdown` will be automatically called following the termination of the `with ... as executor:` block.